# How to use other components functions without rendering the whole component

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs

So how do i use a function of one component into other without rendering the whole component.
Here is my component which's function i want to use:

```
var Signup = React.createClass({
    signUpFunc: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var user = this.refs.user.value;
        var _email = this.refs.email.value;
        var _pass = this.refs.pass.value;

        if (_email && _pass && user !== '' && _email.trim().length && user.trim().length && _pass.trim().length !== 0 ) {
            console.log('Account Created');
        }
    },
    render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
        <h2>Teacher Sign Up</h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.signUpFunc}>
                <label>User Name:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" ref="user" />
                <br />
                <label>Email:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" ref="email" />
                <br />
                <label>Password:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" ref="pass" />
                <br />
                <button>Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

});
```

and down below is the component in which i want to use this function

```
var Login = React.createClass({
    Submit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var email = this.refs.email.value;
        var pass = this.refs.pass.value;

        if (email && pass !== '' && email.trim().length && pass.trim().length !== 0) {

        }
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Teachers Login</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.Submit}>
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" ref="email" />
                    <br />
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" ref="pass" />
                    <br />
                    <button>Login</button>
                    <Link to="/signup"><button>Register</button></Link>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you want to "use"? Why don't you want to render it? Maybe you should simply remove the duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've imported `Signup` into the file with `Login`, you should be able to call `Signup.prototype.signUpFunc.call(this);` inside of Login. That said though, this seems like an anti-pattern to me... Why not put any functions that need to be reused into their own files and import them into both spots?